# Node.js fetch response.json() throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have a backend Spring server with two endpoints: `/museum/{id}` and `/museum/all`. The first one returns a museum object for the given museum id, while the second returns an array with all the museums in the database.

With cURL, both endpoints work perfectly. However, with Node.js fetch, the id one throws a TypeError. The issue originally occurred in my React frontend, but it also occurs in the Node terminal. When I try the all endpoint:

```js
> fetch("http://localhost:8080/museum/all").then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {console.log(data)})
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 792,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 791
}
> [
  {
    *correct museum object*
  }
]
```

But with the id endpoint:

```js
> fetch("http://localhost:8080/museum/1").then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {console.log(data)})
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 934,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 933
}
> Uncaught TypeError: terminated
    at Fetch.onAborted (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14178:53)
    at Fetch.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Fetch.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at Fetch.terminate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13438:14)
    at Object.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14273:36)
    at Request.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7758:31)
    at errorRequest (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9917:17) {
  [cause]: DOMException [AbortError]: The operation was aborted.
      at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)
      at Object.destroy (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14040:33)
      at httpFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13863:45)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13778:18)
      at async node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13654:20
      at async mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13650:20)
}
```

This does not seem to be a backend error as both endpoints work perfectly with cURL. Additionally, if instead of using the above one-liner I first get the response only, I can print the response status which is 302 (what the backend server returns for successful calls). The error/exception only happens when using `response.json()`.

Finally, others working on the same project have no issues with any of this. Both endpoints work correctly with Node. Could this be an issue of Node on Windows 11? My teammates all have macs. I'm using Node v19.2.0.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the value of response before calling .json() ?

Comment: The response seems good: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/eAaUNrD). The status is also good and matches what the backend is supposed to return.

Comment: Your stream field in body is undefined. Why ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not very experienced with web development, so I don't know what could cause this. Is there something I could check which would cause the stream field to be undefined? As I said, with curl everything works and I get the data correctly, so I don't know where the data could get "corrupted". Edit: I just checked with the /all endpoint and the stream field is also undefined. However, calling `response.json()` works correctly with this endpoint.

Comment: Hmm. I'm sure that it's not a client error. It's from the server. Do you have the code which returns the data ?

Comment: Yes, my teammates and I wrote the backend server. It uses Spring boot and the controller methods return RequestEntities